# Get large prime factor in java

Tags: java, prime-factoring

[10392 - Factoring Large Numbers](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&Itemid=99999999&page=show_problem&category=&problem=1333&mosmsg=Submission%20received%20with%20ID%2012715020)

it gives me wrong answer ,I don't know why !!!

Factoring Large Numbers,You may assume that there will be at most one factor more than 1000000. Java code is below

The numbers will fit in gcc's long long int datatype

i worked with big integer class as long long int

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);


    while(sc.hasNextBigInteger())
    {

    BigInteger test = sc.nextBigInteger();
    String e ="-1";
    if(test.compareTo(new BigInteger(e))==0)
    break;
    work(test);


    }

    }
            public static void work(BigInteger n)
            {


                    List<BigInteger>list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
                    String s ="2";

                    for(BigInteger i = new BigInteger(s) ; i.multiply(i).compareTo(n)<=0;i=i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
                    {
                        while(n.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0)
                        {
                            list.add(i);
                            n=n.divide(i);

                        }
                    }

                    if(n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE)>0)
                        list.add(n);


                    for(BigInteger j:list)
                    {
                        System.out.println("\t"+j);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
            }


    }
```

Comment: What is wrong about it? What input are you using, what output does it give you, what do you think it should be? What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: Also, a tab is not the same as four spaces. The online judge may very well be picky about that.

Comment: Also, if `long long int` is 64 bits (which I think it is) you can just use Java's `long`

Comment: i used big integer instead long long